# Should I always use .off('load');?

Tags: jquery

On a porfolio website that has a lot of images, I check what the clients loadtime was and then serve either small or large images. But after loading the smaller set of images, I would like to swap them out for the bigger images.

I used the .on('load') handler for this, but when testing the page, I found that it kept firing. I fixed it by adding the .off('load') handler at the end.

```
$(this).on('load', function() {
  $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('src')).off('load');
  console.log('full size img are loading');
}).attr('src', srcNew);
```

So my question is:

**In all the code snippets online, I never found this use of the .off('load') handler. Is this normal behaviour?**

Maybe it matters that the function is in a loop? Here is the complete function:

```
var loadTime = window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd-window.performance.timing.navigationStart; 

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.fn.lazyLoad = function(){ 
        if($(this).is('img[data-src]')) {
            var lazy = $(this);
        } else {
            var lazy = $(this).find('img[data-src]');
        };
        $(lazy).each(function(){
            if (loadTime > 1000) {
                var src = $(this).data('src');
                var srcPath = src.slice(0, -4);
                var srcExt =    src.slice(-4);
                var srcNew = srcPath + '_s' + srcExt;
                $(this).on('load', function() {
                    $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('src')).off('load');
                    console.log('full size img have been loaded');
                }).attr('src', srcNew);
                console.log('_s img have been loaded');
            } else {
                $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('src'));
            }
        });
    };
    $('.lazy').lazyLoad();
    $('.slide').click(function() {
        $(this).lazyLoad();
    });
});
```

And here the HTML:

```
<img data-src="img/photo.jpg" src="img/photo_s.jpg" alt="" />
```

Comment: Can you show how you are initializing the plugin?

Comment: I added the code in my question. The lazyLoad function gets called on all elements with the .lazy class, or on opening a slideshow with the class .slide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function keeps being called because a `load` event keeps being triggered. When you change the `src` attribute of an image, the browser will load the new source data; when it's done, a new `load` event on that element will fire up the event listener, the same as before.
It's ok to use `.off()` at the end of your function to assure that it only runs once. The same behaviour can be obtained by using [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/).

Comment: .one() seems to be my best bet then. I never realized the event listener would still be listening to the function triggered by it.